# Raphael.js apply transform matrix before raphael.export.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am using the following code to add a svg converterted with rappar and node.js

```
paper.add([{"type":"ellipse","fill":"#858AB5","stroke":"none","cx":241,"cy":241,"rx":243,"ry":243},{"type":"text","fill":"#FFFFFF","stroke":"none","transform":"t87.1509,235.2886s0.9997,1,0,0","font-family":"Impact","font-size":54.0116,"text-anchor":"start","text":"Darma Greg"}]);
```

The problem comes when i go to save it, it saves but without applying the transform.  The text is not in the position it was when you clicked save.

What am i missing?  Is there a way to "apply" the transform, ive tried lot of examples but documentation on Raphael is lacking.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'transform' method with it ?

Comment: I think so.  But could you please specify a little more?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/12999f8e552d74986f6108cef1d20766  Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sooo after a week of debugging this, and thinking it was my code.  It turned out to be the anchor:left set on the text node.  My designer remade the svg set anchor middle, and everything seems to be working fine.